# How to find the number of solutions to an equation with 2 variables

Tags: combinatorics

Say we have an equation $2a + 3b = n$ such that $a$ and $b$ are non-negative integers. How would you go about finding the number of solutions?

Comment: First parametrize all the solutions: $(a,b)=(-n+3k,n-2k)$. Then impose the bounds and solve for the parameter $k$ satisfying all the bounds. For example, $0<-n+3k<n$ yields $k<2n/3$ and $n/3<k$. The condition $0<b<n$ imposes further conditions on $k$.

Answer (score 1):

We can say that the solutions are: $(-n+3k,n-2k)$. Now solutions must be positive: $k<2n/3$ and $n/3<k$. This yields to: $$n/3<k<2n/3$$The number of solutions is: $$N_n = \left \lfloor n/3 \right \rfloor$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's divide into cases.
Case 1: $n = 2k$
Proposition: There are $\lfloor \frac{k}{3} \rfloor + 1$ solutions.

Case 2: $n = 2k + 1$
Proposition: There are $\lfloor \frac{k-1}{3} \rfloor + 1$ solutions.

$\underline{\text{Proof:}}$
For the even case, the proof works as follow:
$b$ must be even, so you could write the equation as $2a+6b'=2k$.
Now $b'$ can get any integer value between $[0,\lfloor \frac{k}{3}\rfloor]\implies b'\ $  have $\lfloor \frac{k}{3}\rfloor + 1$ options, where each of them determines $a$ uniquely.